# ios with xcode dose not reflect the changes ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

When I upload my ionic app ios platform to xcode it builds successfully.  I then ran it on a target device and everything is still fine.

However, when I change anything in my code and rebuild the platform again after deleting the existing platform the code changes are not reflected when I run it again on a target device.

Ionic:

- ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.2.1
- Ionic Framework : ionic-angular 3.9.2
- @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

- cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2
- Cordova Platforms : ios 4.5.5

System:

- ios-deploy : 1.9.4
- ios-sim : 5.0.13
- NodeJS : v9.8.0
- npm : 5.6.0
- OS : macOS High Sierra
- Xcode : Xcode 9.4.1 Build version 9F2000

Answer (score 0):

I also suffered from the same phenomenon.
But it was able to be updated constantly with the following operation.

1. Open your Xcode project. (open platforms/ios/XXX.xcodeproj)
2. Build ionic on CLI or Visual Studio Code or etc. (ionic cordova prepare ios)
3. Run app on Xcode.

Try it, thank you.